# error in accessing file name through get method

Tags: php, file-upload

i am using the `get` method to upload the file and when i write the `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`then it gives the error `Undefined index: file` but if i use the `post` method then it works fine. How can i access the file name or file type.Here is the code of first page.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload2.php" method="GET"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of second page

```
 <?php
 $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 ?>
```

Comment: giving error i don't know what's issue

Comment: other inputs work fine but the only error is when i write this `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files cannot be uploaded through a `GET` request. You need to use `POST`.

The PHP manual's definition for  [**$_FILES**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php):

"An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the ***HTTP POST*** method."

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

Files uploaded through a form using POST method It will always end up in PHP's $_FILES superglobal. while you are using GET method to do that but its not possible as per my knowledge at this condition PHP's $_FILES is not present that's why you are getting  error Undefined index: file.